# How can i get the key of Object inside Array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I have a response data from backend-server like example bellow:

```
[
    {
        id: "haskjdhak",
        name: "lorem ipsun 1",
        desc: "any description 1"
    },
    {
        id: "78khasc",
        name: "lorem ipsun 2",
        desc: "any description 2"
    },
    {
        id: "56jkjn",
        name: "lorem ipsun 3",
        desc: "any description 3"
    }
]
```

my goal is I want to separated that response data into headers and values, where the headers is the `key={id,name,desc}` and the value is value each index.
okay let me give an example that data will become a table data, like this bellow:

| id | name | desc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| haskjdhak | lorem ipsun 1 | any description 1 |
| 78khasc | lorem ipsun 2 | any description 2 |
| 56jkjn | lorem ipsun 3 | any description 3 |

What method can I use for doing it?

Comment: key cannot be an object right. You want a concatenated string? Please post desired sample output

Comment: If you show an example of what the transformed data should look like, it would help clarify your objective. It sounds like you need to iterate over the members of the array and produce an object or [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Comment: Or maybe you're trying to turn an array of objects into a table-like matrix whose header is comprised of the attribute names, and the values for each row are the corresponding values? The way it is describes leaves room for interpretation; as others said, we will need an example.

Comment: yeah, you are right @Haroldo_OK

Comment: so, if any change or update in the backend like the headers will change the name or removed, or add another headers my code in the frontend doesn't change, because i think it will dynamically change depend on data were given from backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the edit on your question, maybe this is more useful:

Using a `Map`, for each `key` you have an array with values.

```js
const response = [
    {id:"haskjdhak", name: "lorem ipsun 1", desc: "any description 1"},
    {id:"78khasc", name: "lorem ipsun 2", desc: "any description 2"},
    {id:"56jkjn", name: "lorem ipsun 3", desc: "any description 3"}
    ]
    
    const map = new Map();
    
    response.map(m => (Object.keys(m).forEach(e => {
      map.get(e) === undefined ? map.set(e, [m[e]]) : map.get(e).push(m[e])
    } )))

    map.forEach((value,key) => {
        console.log(`${key} = ${value}`);
    })
```

Also using `node.JS` using `console.log(map)` directly you can see:

```
Map(3) {
  'id' => [ 'haskjdhak', '78khasc', '56jkjn' ],
  'name' => [ 'lorem ipsun 1', 'lorem ipsun 2', 'lorem ipsun 3' ],
  'desc' => [ 'any description 1', 'any description 2', 'any description 3' ]
}
```

This piece of code get all keys from your object and create a `Map` using the key. If not exists any value for the key, it add an array with the initial value; if exists a value (is not `undefined`) it `push()` the new value.

Also, with this approach your data can contains different keys, for example, with this entry data:

```
const response = [
    { id: "haskjdhak", name: "lorem ipsun 1", desc: "any description 1" },
    { id: "78khasc", name: "lorem ipsun 2", desc: "any description 2" },
    { id: "56jkjn", name: "lorem ipsun 3", desc: "any description 3" },
    {
        id: "1"
    },
    {
        new: "value"
    },
    {
        id: "new", name: "new", desc: "new", other: "new"
    }
]
```

Result is:

```
Map(5) {
  'id' => [ 'haskjdhak', '78khasc', '56jkjn', '1', 'new' ],
  'name' => [ 'lorem ipsun 1', 'lorem ipsun 2', 'lorem ipsun 3', 'new' ],
  'desc' => [
    'any description 1',
    'any description 2',
    'any description 3',
    'new'
  ],
  'new' => [ 'value' ],
  'other' => [ 'new' ]
}
```

**-- Original answer --**

If I've understood correctly you can try this:

```js
const response = [
{id:"haskjdhak", name: "lorem ipsun 1", desc: "any description 1"},
{id:"78khasc", name: "lorem ipsun 2", desc: "any description 2"},
{id:"56jkjn", name: "lorem ipsun 3", desc: "any description 3"}
]

var result = response.map(m => ({key:(Object.keys(m).join(",")), value:(Object.values(m).join(","))}))

console.log("result = ", result)
```

This code create an array with `key/value` objects where `key` are the keys (a string with all values) and `value` is the same for values.

Comment: That will work okay, as long as none of the objects in the original array has a missing key nor an extra key, and as long as the keys are always on the same order. If there's a chance of that condition failing, it would be necessary to take extra steps.

Comment: That's true, I've updated using `Map()` because I think is a better approach for the question and also can admit different objects keys/values.

Answer (score 1):

something like this maybe can help you

```
yourArray.map(obj => ({key:"id, name, desc", value:`${obj.id}, 
${obj.name}, ${obj.desc}`}))
```